# push isn't working after creating new provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

As you know, push - certificate - profile is a mess..

I can't get my head around it..

We recently changed our provisioning profile (or developer/production certificate) and wonder if it's the reason why push isn't working.

Would it affect the push functionality in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got your question correctly

If you app is live, then I assume you have a server to send the notifications to the APNS, now I guess all you have to do is to copy your distribution certificate and replace it on the server instead of the current old one.

Comment: yes, your assumption is correct, we have a server to talk to APNS. ok you answered my question that changing certificate affected the push functionality. Although it isn't as easy as just replace distribution certificate on the server. I remember I dealt with pem file. and my note is pointing at a apple doc that's vaporized..

Comment: you have to generate new pem file from new certificate and place it on the server instead of the old one. some notes on how to do that are here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19031862/653513

Comment: You can simply generate the .pem file, just follow these instructions
http://www.apptuitions.com/generate-pem-file-for-push-notification/